# what can make faster a date column process for python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame that include customer ticket using time.

`ticket_end` data is `not` correct and I have to use `ticket_start` column which is correct and I have customer `ticket_name` which describe how long are the tickets.

I used `relativedelta(months=+numberofmonths)` which is working but I have 300k rows and time is more than 2 hours so I started to find other options but all same then I tried this code again it only took 5 mins! I did not changed again but I do not know what happened but I had to start kernel again and now it is taking more than 2 hours again.

My question is I do not know why it happened? and What can we do for making datetime column process faster?

Here is my code:

```
for i in tqdm(range(len(customer))):
    if  customer.ticket_name[i] == '3 month free':
        customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+1)

    elif customer.product_name[i] == '4 month free':  
         customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+4)

    elif customer.product_name[i] == '6 month free':
         customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+6)

    elif customer.product_name[i] == '9 month free': 
         customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+9)

    else:
        customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

before the code, the date columns was string and date and time `'2015-01-28 17:59:50'`

I do not needed so I removed the time with this:

```
customer['ticket_start']= pd.to_datetime(customer['ticket_start'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
customer['ticket_start'] = map(lambda x: x.date(), customer['ticket_start'])
```

again `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
customer['ticket_start']= pd.to_datetime(customer['ticket_start'])
```

might be critical information I got data both from `csv` and from a database with `mysql.connector`
 but now both are a process 2 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for remove times [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), then creare new column for `months` and last add them by `DateOffset`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03  15:14:01', periods=30, freq='300H')
customer = pd.DataFrame({'ticket_start': rng, 'product_name': ['3 month free'] * 5 + 
                                                              ['4 month free'] * 5 + 
                                                              ['6 month free'] * 10 +
                                                              ['9 month free'] * 5 +
                                                              ['2 month free'] * 5} )  


#print (customer)

customer['ticket_start']=(pd.to_datetime(customer['ticket_start'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                            .dt.floor('d'))
d = {'3 month free' : 1, '4 month free': 4, '6 month free':6, '9 month free':9}
customer['m'] = customer['product_name'].map(d).fillna(1).astype(int) 


customer['ticket_end'] = customer.apply(lambda x: x['ticket_start'] + 
                                    pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x['m']), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (customer)
    product_name ticket_start  m ticket_end
0   3 month free   2017-01-03  1 2017-02-03
1   3 month free   2017-01-16  1 2017-02-16
2   3 month free   2017-01-28  1 2017-02-28
3   3 month free   2017-02-10  1 2017-03-10
4   3 month free   2017-02-22  1 2017-03-22
5   4 month free   2017-03-07  4 2017-07-07
6   4 month free   2017-03-19  4 2017-07-19
7   4 month free   2017-04-01  4 2017-08-01
8   4 month free   2017-04-13  4 2017-08-13
9   4 month free   2017-04-26  4 2017-08-26
10  6 month free   2017-05-08  6 2017-11-08
11  6 month free   2017-05-21  6 2017-11-21
12  6 month free   2017-06-02  6 2017-12-02
13  6 month free   2017-06-15  6 2017-12-15
14  6 month free   2017-06-27  6 2017-12-27
15  6 month free   2017-07-10  6 2018-01-10
16  6 month free   2017-07-22  6 2018-01-22
17  6 month free   2017-08-04  6 2018-02-04
18  6 month free   2017-08-16  6 2018-02-16
19  6 month free   2017-08-29  6 2018-02-28
20  9 month free   2017-09-10  9 2018-06-10
21  9 month free   2017-09-23  9 2018-06-23
22  9 month free   2017-10-05  9 2018-07-05
23  9 month free   2017-10-18  9 2018-07-18
24  9 month free   2017-10-30  9 2018-07-30
25  2 month free   2017-11-12  1 2017-12-12
26  2 month free   2017-11-24  1 2017-12-24
27  2 month free   2017-12-07  1 2018-01-07
28  2 month free   2017-12-19  1 2018-01-19
29  2 month free   2018-01-01  1 2018-02-01
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution @jezrael. This code is not the only a minute for my data. Thank you. What is the floor, what is the behind this?

Comment: I test it deeply and I find small problem, need `customer['m'] = customer['product_name'].map(d).fillna(1).astype(int) + customer['ticket_start'].dt.month` instead `customer['m'] = customer['product_name'].map(d).fillna(1).astype(int)`

Comment: And for your second question - [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) is for truncate datetimes, e.g. for remove times `df.floor('d')`, for remove minutes `df.floor('h')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an error with your correction code, The error: `IllegalMonthError: bad month number 13; must be 1-12`. Also yes I found something which is when you give 1 in fillna() the data that you did not point out `ticket_start` time being random. I gave 0 then all not point out data same been ticket_start

Comment: I edit answer to end. I add fillna(1) for default month `1` from `else:
customer.ticket_end[i] = customer.ticket_start[i] + relativedelta(months=+1)`

Comment: I just realised that add month 1,2,6,9 are being added beginning of year, not an addition on the ticket_start

Comment: If check edited answer, it add first `m1` and then `m2`, so it should working nice.

Comment: I am sorry @jezrael I got this for m2 = `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: I remove timings and add only answer. please check it.

Comment: I test it deeply and first solution was correct ;) I edit answer with larger data sample

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for all @jezrael